# Lenovo ThinkPad Mini Dock Series 3 with USB (433715U)

Tags: multiple-monitors, connection, thinkpad, docking-station

I am purchasing Lenovo brand docking stations for EOL laptops. I found a few  `Lenovo ThinkPad Mini Dock Series 3 with USB (433715U)` through a distributor.

Do these include connections for dual monitoring and the ability to charge the laptop?

Answer (score 1):

From: https://support.lenovo.com/gb/en/documents/pd024298

> Multiple video ports:
>
> ```
> Port Replicator: 1x VGA
> Mini Dock: 1x VGA, 1x DVI, 1x DP
>     The video controller allows for any two video ports to be used simultaneously.
> ```
>
> Included AC Adapter
>
> ```
> Port Replicator: None
> Mini Dock: 90W AC Adapter
> Mini Dock Plus 90W: 90W AC Adapter
> Mini Dock Plus 170W: 170W AC Adapter
> ```